# Change the default-view of Media Library in 3.5?

Tags: media-library

When inserting media into a post, is there a way to change the default-view of the Media-Library from "All media items" to "Uploaded to this post"?

[image: borrowed Screenshot]

There is another thread where this question was extracted from:
[How to manage attachment relationships](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76048/how-to-manage-attachment-relationships-for-specific-posts-in-wp-3-5)

Comment: Have you tried turning off all other plugins, switch back to the default theme and then just activating the one from toscho? Could possible be a JS conflict.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There were two minor mistakes in my previous answer:

1. I forgot to trigger the `change` event for the parent.
2. I called the function on every AJAX call, making other selections impossible.

Here is the fixed code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Pre-select post specific attachments
 */

add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'wpse_76048_script' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'wpse_76048_script' );

function wpse_76048_script()
{
    ?>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var called = 0;
    $('#wpcontent').ajaxStop(function() {
        if ( 0 == called ) {
            $('[value="uploaded"]').attr( 'selected', true ).parent().trigger('change');
            called = 1;
        }
    });
});
</script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, toscho! <br>The plugin-code you dropped here works like a charm for me now! *(it would be nice if someone can convert this "answer" into a comment and set the status to answered)*

Comment: You are the only one who can tick the _answer_ check mark. You have to use the account you used for asking. I merged both accounts, you should be able to tick the check mark now. :)

Comment: This very elegant code works when you click the `Add Media` button but not when you click the `Set featured image`. Is there a way to make it work there as well?

Comment: It does work on my system for featured images too.

Comment: This has a potential problem, it looks like you're selecting *everything* that has value=uploaded. Also, if you wanted to add javascript to *initialization* of every uploader, `wp.media.view.UploaderWindow.prototype.on('ready',function() {console.log(jQuery('.media-modal-content'))...your code here...});` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with Create Gallery and Featured Image?

Answer (score 13):

The only problem with the JS above that it toggles the select box to trigger the change after the page loads and after its already begun to download ALL MEDIA ITEMS. For my client on a slow T1 this locked things up as it downloaded both the ALL MEDIA TIMES and the UPLOADED TO THIS POST items together.

I had some help from the great Sewpafly who develops [Post Thumbnail Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/) Plugin.  he shared a great piece of JS that prevents the load of ALL MEDIA ITEMS and forces it to load only images "UPLOADED TO THIS POST" by default.

### The Code

**File:** myadmin.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var called = 0;
    $('#wpcontent').ajaxStop(function() {
        if ( 0 == called ) {
            $('[value="uploaded"]').attr( 'selected', true ).parent().trigger('change');
            called = 1;
        }
    });
  var oldPost = wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post;
    wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post = oldPost.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            oldPost.prototype.initialize.apply( this, arguments );
            this.states.get('insert').get('library').props.set('uploadedTo', wp.media.view.settings.post.id);
        }
    });
});
```

**File:** functions.php

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_js');
function add_admin_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('admin_js', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/admin.js');
}
```

The same code on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/fishnyc22/5593693

I dropped that into a JS file and called it in functions.php with the admin_enqueue_scripts. See GIST above for both the PHP and JS.

Works brilliantly. Hopefully the fine wordpress folks fix this in a upcoming update, but for now [Sewpafly](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/) has the best solution I've found. Thanks again buddy.

I should note that I have just discovered that the viewer defaults to MEDIUM sized images which I had disabled (set to 0,0) since I was not using and preventing bloat. When medium size isn't available wordpress loads the FULL size image. I have since given in enabled the medium size.

Comment: extremely helpful - can one not just limit the number of images that display in the media library with some type of hook?

Comment: Personally, I also like to add this CSS which will hide the media dropdown: http://pastebin.com/1dP6SR4g

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution suffers from one major issue. Do the following: 1. Open a post in post-edit screen. 2. Click on the "Set featured image" link (before clicking on the Add Media button). 3. The code works fine so far. Now, close the window and then click on the Add Media button. You will see that the "All media" option is selected **but** it is displaying the uploaded ones. In order to toggle to all the images, you will need to toggle to uploaded, and then back to all media. Do anyone have a solution to this problem? Thank you for this nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

@toscho Ah, I found a bug in your code. Please bare with me. Do the exact following to replicate the issue:

1) Open a draft post.

2) Click on `Add Media` button. Wait for the jQuery function to load.

3) On your left, click on the `Set Featured Image` link.

4) Now close the Media popup window and on the post edit page, click on the `Set featured image` link on the right side-bar.

5) You will see that the jQuery function will not work.

However, if you would have clicked on the `Set featured image` link first on post edit load, the function would work. Can you replicate this issue and possibly find a solution? Sorry again for posting this as an answer but this platform does not offer me a better option currently.

EDIT: Can someone please let **toscho** know about this. You can do this by adding a comment to his answer which I believe should give him a notification. I cannot write comments as I do not have enough reputation...

**EDIT 2**: If you want to desperately avoid this issue, you can remove the "Set Featured Image" link in the popup and force the user to use the sidebar link (like WP versions prior to 3.5). Use this filter that was introduced in WP 3.5:

```
add_filter( 'media_view_strings', 'cor_media_view_strings' );
/**
 * @see wp-includes|media.php
 */
function cor_media_view_strings( $strings ) {
    unset( $strings['setFeaturedImageTitle'] );
    return $strings;
}
```

As I said, this is a desperate fix until there is a solution posted for the main code.

Comment: I am aware of this, I just have no time to extend the plugin.

Comment: I understand, if you would to find the time in the near future to extend it, we would all be grateful.

Comment: I updated this *answer* with a "wordaround" for the desperate ones. toscho you can add this to your answer if you wish...

Answer (score 2):

The main thing I didn't like about most of these solutions is that it was blinking on alot of screens, and if you clicked on **Featured Image** it would revert back to showing all images. After some searching I think found a permanent solution (Thanks to [Ünsal Korkmaz](http://unsalkorkmaz.com/how-to-lock-uploads-to-show-only-uploaded-to-this-post-in-media-panel/)) which looks like it solves these problems. The code:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'media_library_filter' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'media_library_filter' );
function media_library_filter() { 
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", function(){
            jQuery('select.attachment-filters [value="uploaded"]').attr( 'selected', true ).parent().trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
}
```

which permanently sets the media library to only show "Uploaded To This Post", even if you try and change the view which means no blinking.

I've added this code to accompany it to remove the selectbox entirely:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_select_ddl' );
function hide_select_ddl()
{
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
    div.media-menu a.media-menu-item:nth-child(3) {display:none!important;}
    .media-frame-content .attachment-filters:first-child {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The new versions of wordpress use a different approach (advanced [Backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/)) for the media uploader; 
Check the code from [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/default-media-uploader-view) as it works for new versions of WordPress.

Comment: Would have been nice if you actually shared the code – not just a link.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solutions to set `dateFilter` to current month, though it triggers AJAX twice.

```
.on('content:render:browse', function(a, b) {
  var filter = a.toolbar.secondary.get('dateFilter');           
  if (filter.model) {
    filter.model.set(filter.filters[1].props);
  }
})
```