# Allow only attachment uploaded to current post

Tags: uploads, media-library

The "Add Media" button allows any media to be added to current editor. I need the "Uploaded to this page" from the dropdown menu to be the only option available. Some time ago I found a solution somewhere like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", function(){
        // Lock uploads to "Uploaded to this post"
        $('select.attachment-filters [value!="uploaded"]').remove()
        $('select.attachment-filters').trigger('change');
    });
})
```

However, this event conflicts with my other plugin because that plugin will insert more than 100 nodes and this code snippet will slow that process down very much: it takes 2 minutes longer to load with this event attached.

Therefore, I am looking for a better solution that will save the time and browser's resource here. Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I was over thinking, but the solution is easier than I thought.

I just have to limit the event handler to some element, so other unrelated ones will not trigger the handler. In this case, `.media-modal` is the overall parent of the media library element, so I am specifying this extra selector to the event, like below:

```
jQuery(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", '.media-modal', function() {
    // ...
}
```

And after testing, this will speed up the other insertion of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've found which I use regularly. Really it's the same thing you're using but placing it into the admin footer so that it's one of the last things to load. Maybe it's faster?

```
function media_library_filter(){ 
    ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", function(){
            jQuery('select.attachment-filters [value="uploaded"]').attr( 'selected', true ).parent().trigger('change');
        });
      </script>
    <?php 
}
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'media_library_filter' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'media_library_filter' );
```

You can view this but it's kind of old:

[Change the default-view of Media Library in 3.5?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/change-the-default-view-of-media-library-in-3-5/140284#140284)

Comment: Nice idea but those 100 nodes are inserted when a certain button is clicked, so we don't know when they will be inserted.